# Failed to start Postgres on Debian

Tags: linux, postgresql, permissions, debian

Postgres (13.5) cannot start after restarting server (Debian 4.19.208-1)

**UPDATE 1**
I changed user permissions and now I have another error on starting postgres:
`systemctl status postgresql`
**FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists**

But I checked pg clusters and there exists only one:
[image]

Also I deleted postmaster.pid and there is no file any more:
[image]

So I have no errors details but postrges is shutting down.
[image]

**Any ideas?**

==============================================================
I'm trying to start manually `sudo service postgresql start` but got error:

**Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

So then I ran `systemctl status postgresql`
Results:

**`FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/13/main" has invalid permissions`**
**`DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).`**

I modified permissions:
`chmod u=rwx /var/lib/postgresql/13/main`
`chmod g=rx /var/lib/postgresql/13/main`

But I still see the same error about permissions.

You can see whole results on screenshot
[image]

*Sorry, I'm not so familiar with Linux*

Comment: try with sudo chmod 0700 -R /var/lib/postgresql/13 // g=rx is the problem, only postgres user must have access

Comment: Is user important to run chmod (root or postgres)?

I tried:
`root@vm-reestr1:/home/borm# sudo chmod 0700 -R /var/lib/postgresql/13`

Current permissions:
`drwx------ 19 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  5 18:40 main`

And I got another error after start:

**FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists**  
**HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 17668) running in data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/13/main"?**

Comment: Run `pg_lsclusters` from command line to see what Postgres instances are running. If that does not work then: `ps ax | grep postgres`.

Comment: Only single instance:  
  
root@vm-reestr1:/home/borm# pg_lsclusters  

`Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
13  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log`

Comment: Then Postgres is running. Do: `sudo systemctl restart  postgresql@13-main.service` to restart it.

Comment: `root@vm-reestr1:~# sudo systemctl restart  postgresql@13-main.service`  

`root@vm-reestr1:~# sudo service postgresql start`  

**Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.**

Comment: Where did you install Postgres from? I see Postgres Pro in the status and that is not the community edition.

Comment: Yes, now it's Pro version. But I don't know which version was installed before it. How can I check it? In syslog files?

Comment: `dpkg -l| grep postgres`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. I ran postgres not as a service but **with logs**:
**`postgresql -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main`**
And I saw in the log that problem was with `pg_hba.conf`. I opened this file - it was empty!
So I restored pg_hba.conf from backup and started postgres as service